# Rails: Postgres Database in Heroku (probably dumb questions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've never really been a database guy. I'm using Postgres and in my database.yml, I have:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_test
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I'm pushing this to heroku soon and just have a few concerns. Here are my questions (they may be dumb questions but I couldn't find anything on google that addresses this in a simple way):

**1. Will heroku set this up for me using my herokue password? Should I just leave this file as is?**

**2. How can I test that my database is secured  by a password?**

**3. What's the point of even having this file? Am I not the only one that can easily access my Rails files (without hacking ofcourse)?**

Thank you in advance. I'm using postgresapp & am deploying on heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be worth checking out [Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) documentation. The key point is that when you upload to Heroku, Heroku replaces the `database.yml` file with an automatically generated one that handles the setup. The only point to the `database.yml` file you have locally is to manage connections to your development and test databases (and a local production one, if you choose to have some sort of local staging environment or whatnot).

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the production entry from your database.yml file.

> When Rails applications are deployed to Heroku a database.yml file is
>   automatically generated for your application that configures
>   ActiveRecord to use a PostgreSQL connection and to connect to the
>   database located at DATABASE_URL.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-rails

Answer (score 2):

Heroku actually overwrites yourdatabase.yml with its own when you deploy.  This means you don't have to worry about any db name/username/pw etc.

That stuff does exist and is accessible if you need it, but by default Heroku "knows" about it and will setup your connection automatically.

If you want to take a look at your DB you can go here: https://postgres.heroku.com/databases. That will give you the database's name and login credentials for your app.